# whenever cronjob in Rails app in docker container not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, whenever

I am setting a cronjob by whenever inside docker container.
Everything looks fine but it's not work.

Here is part of my code.

Gemfile:

```
gem 'whenever', :require => false
```

config/schedule.rb

```
set :output, "log/cron.log"
env :PATH, ENV['PATH']
set :environment, 'development'

every 1.day, :at => '1:00 am' do
  rake "import"
end

every 1.minute do
  p "#{Time.now}!"
  rake "cron_test"
end
```

And my dockerfile

```
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential libpq-dev cron postgresql-client-9.4 dos2unix
RUN touch $APP_HOME/log/cron.log
RUN bundle exec whenever --update-crontab
CMD cron && bundle exec puma
```

When I run `whenever`, I get

```
PATH=/usr/local/bundle/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin

0 1 * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /mlcot && RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rake import --silent >> log/cron.log 2>&1'

* * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /mlcot && RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rake cron_test --silent >> log/cron.log 2>&1'

## [message] Above is your schedule file converted to cron syntax; your crontab file was not updated.
## [message] Run `whenever --help' for more options.
```

I make any check I can find from google, but there still nothing happen. I don't even get `log/cron.log` file.

But if I direct run 
`/bin/bash -l -c 'cd /mlcot && RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rake cron_test --silent'`

It works. Any suggestion or advice will be appreciate.

Answer (score 4):

I solved it by add this.

Dockfile:

```
RUN gem install bundler --version 1.11.2

# another line

CMD cron -f && bundle exec puma
```

And add this line to `schedule.rb`

```
ENV.each { |k, v| env(k, v) }
```

Thanks [here](https://github.com/javan/whenever/issues/698) and [here](https://github.com/javan/whenever/issues/656#issuecomment-239111064).